# How to make a "for" for updating dates in solidity?

Tags: solidity, chainlink

I made a smart contract based on NBA data , I used chain link oracle to make a API request .
so I also set up an Upkeep contract to keep my contract and data alive .
but the problem is I want to update my data by date , for example I want have 11/16/2022 Data but it hardcoded in the chain link request . how can I write a "for" to update my dates in the API ?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have to call the function yourself anyway, why not just pass the date in as an argument? Would look like

```
function requestMultiVariable(string memory URI) public {
    Chainlink.Request memory req = // same thing as snippet
    req.add("get", URI);
    // rest of your code
}
```

If you really want to do string manipulation, check out the [solidity-stringutils](https://github.com/Arachnid/solidity-stringutils) library. A dummy implementation for producing a string with a dynamic date, still requiring you to pass in a date string, is below:

```
import "https://github.com/Arachnid/solidity-stringutils/blob/master/src/strings.sol";

contract StringManipulation {
    using strings for *;

    string endpoint = 'https://api.sportsdata.io/v3/nba/scores/json/TeamGameStatsByDate';
    string key = '/YOUR_KEY';

    function createString(string memory dateString) public view returns(string memory uri) {
        strings.slice[] memory stringArr = new strings.slice[](3);
        stringArr[0] = endpoint.toSlice();
        stringArr[1] = dateString.toSlice();
        stringArr[2] = key.toSlice();
        uri = strings.join(''.toSlice(),stringArr);           
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I learned something new , and sorry for the late answer I'm suffering from internet connection vulnerability .. after your hint I used to write a for but it seems that it makes it complicated .. So I decided to change the API at all to get a better data form , is it possible to directly change the API in the picture ? or it needs to be config a new oracle and EA ?